# jQuery for displaying div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I want a dialog div to appear and rest page to be greyed out. I should not be able to click anything else on page.
Following is the code I am using. Somehow the code is not working. Page just refreshes on click of hyperlink.
Can anyone help ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#DownloadButton").click(function (e) {
                    ShowDialog(true);
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                $("#btnClose").click(function (e) {
                    HideDialog();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                $("#btnDownload").click(function (e) {
                    HideDialog();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

            });

            function ShowDialog(modal) {
                $("#overlay").show();
                $("#dialog").fadeIn(310);

                if (modal) {
                    $("#overlay").unbind("click");
                }
                else {
                    $("#overlay").click(function (e) {
                        HideDialog();
                    });
                }
            }

            function HideDialog() {
                $("#overlay").hide();
                $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);
            } 

</script>




<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <div id="overlay" class="web_dialog_overlay">
        </div>
        <div id="dialog" class="web_dialog">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="DownloadButton" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div  class="BaseClass">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadButton" runat="server">Download</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
                <asp:GridView>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: preventDefault() show come first before any line, that will at least stop the page from refreshing.

Comment: preventDefault should be the first line to ensure that the default behavior is not fired

Comment: What is not working ? give some details of what steps you do, what is not work and what you expect to do...

Comment: will you please post your .aspx page code aswell as .cs code

Comment: I want Dialog div/table to come up on page when I click on "DownloadButton" hyperlink and the rest page should be greyed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If DownloadButton, btnClose & btnDownload are IDs of server control, then for getting client ID you have to use:

```
$("#<%=DownloadButton.ClientID%>")
```

instead of

```
 $("#DownloadButton")
```

in you jQuery Code.

Or

**If you are using ASP.Net 4.0**

Use ClientIDMode="static" with your server side controls.

**For Closing the Dialog:**

Use link to close the model popup: 
Eg.

```
<a href="#" id="btnClose"></a>
```

and in you Javascript use:

```
$("#btnClose").click(function (e) {
                    HideDialog();
                });
```

Comment: Kapil, this solved the issue, but on click of close button, my page is refreshing again. Any way to stop that postback ?

Comment: For Closing the Dialog, Use link to close the dialog. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use simply anchor tag? it won't cause a postback at least, no need to use update panel.

```
<a id="DownloadButton" href="#">Download</a>

$("#DownloadButton").click(function (e) {
                ShowDialog(true);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

Otherwise Kapil Khandelwal answer is correct if you want to use server side control.

```
$("#<%=DownloadButton.ClientID%>")
```

Comment: I think that use asp.net control inside the updatepanel to update it on code behind with the link.

Answer (score 1):

In document ready:

```
        jQuery("#overlay").dialog(
            {
                bgiframe: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 800
            }
        );
```

in the click event:

```
        $('#overlay').dialog('open');
```

You'll have to specify more options in the dialog declaration, I'm sure, but this approach is working fine for me.